# PagedListAdapter using huge memory when RecyclerView is scrolled long way

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

After long time searching I could not find any implementation of `PagedListAdapter` with raw `SQLiteDatabase`. Now I have implemented one for test purpose and it's working fine.

MyViewModel.class

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel;
import androidx.paging.LivePagedListBuilder;
import androidx.paging.PagedList;

public class MyViewModel extends ViewModel {
    public final LiveData<PagedList<User>> usersList;
    public MyViewModel() {
        usersList = new LivePagedListBuilder<>(new MyFactory(),20).build();
    }
}
```

MyFactory.class

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.paging.DataSource;

public class MyFactory extends DataSource.Factory<Integer, User> {

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public DataSource<Integer, User> create() {
        return new MyDataSource();
    }
}
```

MyDataSource.class

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.paging.PositionalDataSource;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MyDataSource extends PositionalDataSource<User> {
    @Override
    public void loadInitial(@NonNull LoadInitialParams params, @NonNull LoadInitialCallback<User> callback) {
        List<User> userList = new ArrayList<>();
        SQLiteDatabase database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(MainActivity.databasePath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("select id,text from content limit ?,?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(params.requestedStartPosition),String.valueOf(params.requestedLoadSize)});
        while (cursor.moveToNext())
            userList.add(new User(cursor.getInt(0), cursor.getString(1)));
        cursor.close();
        database.close();
        callback.onResult(userList, params.requestedStartPosition, 7000/*test only*/);
    }

    @Override
    public void loadRange(@NonNull LoadRangeParams params, @NonNull LoadRangeCallback<User> callback) {
        List<User> userList = new ArrayList<>();
        SQLiteDatabase database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(MainActivity.databasePath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("select id,text from content limit ?,?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(params.startPosition),String.valueOf(params.loadSize)});
        while (cursor.moveToNext())
            userList.add(new User(cursor.getInt(0), cursor.getString(1)));
        cursor.close();
        database.close();
        callback.onResult(userList);
    }
}
```

But when `RecyclerView` is scrolled down, more data is loaded into list along with all data from the very begining. Thats why memory usage is increasing gradually and app slows down.

Should I recycle old data manually?
or Am I missing something?

Comment: You can configure the maxSize on the PagedList.Config that can be passed to the builder. https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/paging/PagedList.Config

Comment: Thanks @Dan Harms
Another problem: when I use LinearLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset() adapter loads all pages in between. Could you please help?

Comment: That's expected. If you find that users will be scrolling to position often, consider restructuring how your requests are done (eg. reversing your paging order if always going to the bottom).

Comment: I didn't expected that. Anyway thanks for helping, at least I will stop searching now.